# Is there any faster methods to restore db other than mysql dump or export data

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a db of 1.3 TB hosted in a ubuntu server. I want take backup of the db every week.

I have searched in google and many articles which suggested mysql dump or db export.

I wonder that is there any way faster than these methods because dump takes a longer time to restore db in case of any disaster. Is there any more reliable , efficient and faster way to restore db.

My main agenda is to restore the db in a quick way.

Comment: That said, I use [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple tools to backup and restore mysql faster like innobackupex , mysqlbackup , mydumper , mysqlpump. Personally  innobackupex , mysqlbackup should be an ideal choice for databases in TBs. else you can try out my dumper as well. mysqldump is not a recommended solution for huge databases in 100s+ GBs

Answer (score 0):

- Replication provides a "continual" backup.  Zero downtime.  You could stop the Replica to take the backup, but you don't have to touch the Primary.
- LVM provides a way to back up even a terabyte in a minute or so.

Both of those require setup.